# how to configure Result Source to get data from two content sources in SharePoint 2016?

Tags: search, 2016, result-source

I have created multiple content sources in Search application in SharePoint 2016.

In specific search scenario I want result from only two content sources (1. Local SharePoint sites & 2. contractadministration) for this I am trying to create one Result Sources but in "Launch Query Builder" section I am confused how to write query under "Query text" so that I can call these two content sources.

Please just provide me query which call these two content sources.

I googled many article but not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the OOB Managed Property `ContentSource`? Like `{?{SearchTerms} (ContentSource="Local SharePoint Sites" OR ContentSource=contractadministration)` You may have to play with what the actual value of ContentSource is returning to get the query just right.